# Variable is not visible in test class

Tags: unit-test

Can any one help me on this Error as `**Variable is not visible**` in a test class.Any help very much appreciated.

Code :

```
 public with sharing class InvoiceController {
 List<wrapperClass> appointmentList {get;set;}//These three lines are not 
 List<wrapperClass> appointmentList1 {get;set;} //covered in test class
 public list<string> address{get;set;}//

}
```

Test Class :

```
InvoiceController icwc = new InvoiceController(sc);
    icwc.appointmentList=icwc.getappointmentList();
    icwc.appointmentList1=icwc.getappointmentList1();
```

The system throws an Error as :

```
Variable is not visible: appointmentList 
 icwc.appointmentList=icwc.getappointmentList();
```

Similarly for the other

```
Variable is not visible: appointmentList1 
 icwc.appointmentList1=icwc.getappointmentList1();
```

Comment: The properties you are trying to access do not have an access modifier.

Comment: Yep. Default access modifier is `private`.

Comment: I did not know that. That's good to know. Makes sense though. I prefer to add the `private` keyword to be more explicit.

Answer (score 8):

That's because you did not label your properties as public (you don't have an access modifier at all) in your class. **I am going under the assumption that you wanted these List to be accessible publicly.**

If you do this:

```
public List<wrapperClass> AppointmentList { get;set; }
public List<wrapperClass> AppointmentList1 { get;set; }
```

they will be accessible in your test class.

If it is not meant to be visible i.e. `private`, you should specify it as such with the keyword `private` and you **can** use the `@TestVisible` annotation as suggested. **However this should be a last resort!**

Before you do that however, you should do the following:

- Try to figure out if there is a way to populate it in your test method
- See if the property is actually necessary
- Find another way to initialize the property in your class so you code is actually testable

**If you cannot find a way to populate your `private` properties, after you have exhausted all options, then you can use the `@TestVisible` annotation.**

Here would be an example:

```
@TestVisible private List<wrapperClass> AppointmentList { get;set; }
@TestVisible private List<wrapperClass> AppointmentList1 { get;set; }
```

Answer (score 4):

Use TestVisible annotations for private class variables to be accessed in test classes. Please refer
https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_annotation_testvisible.htm

Comment: This to me is not a valid answer. This is simply a band-aid to the actual issue. Using the `@TestVisible` annotation should only be a last resort, which in this case, it's not. It is simply an issue with not adding an access modifier - adding `public`.

Comment: @ProgrammableMedley I would disagree. A property should not be made public simply because it is to be accessed in a test class. This is the core reason for providing "@TestVisible" annotation.

Comment: That is not what I'm implying at all. Simply adding the `public` keyword to make it testable is not what I'm getting at, nor would I ever endorse. I believe the OP thought his properties were `public` without the access modifier. Also, the `@TestVisible` annotation was provided so you can access variable in test, __when you could not properly recreate the actual test scenario in your test class__. What you are suggesting is simply adding the `@TestVisible` annotation without even attempting to make your code testable.

Comment: Oh , got it. Yes I agree, would have been better to cover basics first. I was assuming that this would be obvious for the developer.